# How to forbid insertions, updates and deletes of a Model in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, eloquent

I have a Model like this:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'legacy_foo_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_foo';
}
```

In my use case I must not delete, nor insert nor update the data in the database. I would like that my Model blocked these operations in the application. I can't change the table to be read-only, create a view nor change the database connection to be read-only.

So, how do I forbid changes in the database, in my software, without changing the database, while keeping Eloquent's queries and Object-Relational mapping? Even better if, when a change is attempted, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create trait like this [example](https://github.com/michaelachrisco/ReadOnlyTraitLaravel/blob/master/src/ReadOnlyTrait.php)

```
class User extends Model {
  use ReadOnlyTrait;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you can't change anything on the table itself, but can you create a new user that has read only access to that table? If possible that would be the best route. Otherwise you can update the model to restrict those methods.

You can override the update save and delete methods to throw an exception. On your model add:

```
public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
{
    throw new \Exception('Updates are not allowed');
}

public function save(array $options = [])
{
    throw new \Exception('Updates are not allowed');
}

public function delete()
{
    throw new \Exception('Deleting is not allowed');
}
```

This will stop you from doing these methods on an instance of the model so doing stuff like this will result in an exception.

```
$model->update(['attribute' => 'new value']);
$model->delete();

$model->attribute = 'new value';
$model->save();
```

**It will not prevent you from updating the table with the query builder.** So you could still do this:

```
Foo::where('condition', '=', 'test')->update(['attribute' => 'new value']);
```

Blocking this would require you to implement a custom query builder which would take a lot more effort.